# c gtk3 style - button's background doesn't change

Tags: c, gtk3

I wrote program using GTK3 with css styling and it works perfect on my KDE.
But problem is that on ubuntu and windows 10 styling only works partially.
I have css file like this:

```
window {
    background-color: white;
}
button {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: #555555;
}
```

Everything works except changing background of buttons.
It's how I load css:

```
GtkCssProvider *provider = gtk_css_provider_new ();
gtk_css_provider_load_from_path (provider, "styles.css", NULL);

gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen(gdk_screen_get_default(),
                        GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER(provider),
                        GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution:

```
window {
    background-color: white;
}
button {
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
button > label{
    padding: 15px 32px;
    background-color: #555555;
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change by writing css on `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`.

```css
button.titlebutton.close:backdrop {
  background-color: transparent;
}

button.titlebutton.close {
  background-color: @theme_selected_bg_color;
}
```

References:

- https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme/issues/370#issuecomment-481256130
- https://asukiaaa.blogspot.com/2022/07/change-color-of-close-button-of-ubuntu2204.html